# jQuery tabs not displaying as expected

Tags: jquery, tabs

i am using jquery UI tabs, it not showing my tab3 content.. and sometimes it third tab content is attached to the end of tab2 content.. Any ideas??i here is my code.. and sorry for the messy code... and thanks in advances..

```
    <body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">My Info</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">My Member</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">My schedule</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1"></div>
        <div id="tabs-2">Welcome trainer1
            <br>
            <br>
            <form id="form11" name="form11" action="action2.php" method="post">
                <table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tick</td>
                        <td>MemberName</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                        </td>
                        <td>member1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                        </td>
                        <td>member2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                        </td>
                        <td>member3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <input type='submit' id='submit10' value='Add Member' />
                    <input type='submit' id='submit11' value='Delete Member' />
            </form>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">tab 3</div>
                </div>
</body>
```

i am finding that the closing form and some div are not proper, by red marks in fiddle and mozilla... i checked all tags, but no idea where i went wrong... HELP!!!!!

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP. Also, an example posted at jsFiddle.net is always helpful.

Comment: Double check if you're closing the tags properly. It's 99% of the time what causes this kind of problem.

Comment: @j08691 i have updated..

Comment: @MelanciaUK updated.. if u could say where am wrong..

Comment: We'll need your JS too.

Comment: i tried fiddle for the first time..this is link.. http://jsfiddle.net/frDrG/.. but it is not showing the proper way what i get,may be am not postin it properly der..

Comment: thank you all for ur time.. i appreciate it!!! and my code is working!! Thank again all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just forgotten to close the table tag:

```
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">My Info</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">My Member</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">My schedule</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1"></div>
        <div id="tabs-2">Welcome trainer1
            <br>
            <br>
            <form id="form11" name="form11" action="action2.php" method="post">
                <table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tick</td>
                        <td>MemberName</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        </td>
                        <td>member1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        </td>
                        <td>member2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        </td>
                        <td>member3</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>

                <input type='submit' id='submit10' value='Add Member' />
                <input type='submit' id='submit11' value='Delete Member' />
            </form>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">tab 3</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help you out. :)

Answer (score 1):

On the updated info you are missing closing table tag

```
</table>
```